# Does Bitcoin Core really use random delay in transaction relay?

Tags: bitcoin-core, relay, transaction-propagation

I read that bitcoin uses random delay when relaying transaction to other peers in order to protect privacy. When I read the [source code of the newest Bitcoin Core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin), I found a function called `rand_uniform_delay`. When I searched for its usage, I found it only used in `random_test.cpp`. I wonder where the code for the random delay in Bitcoin Core can be found.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Code used for better privacy when relaying transactions in `\src\net_processing.cpp`:

```
        if (auto tx_relay = peer->GetTxRelay(); tx_relay != nullptr) {
                LOCK(tx_relay->m_tx_inventory_mutex);
                // Check whether periodic sends should happen
                bool fSendTrickle = pto->HasPermission(NetPermissionFlags::NoBan);
                if (tx_relay->m_next_inv_send_time < current_time) {
                    fSendTrickle = true;
                    if (pto->IsInboundConn()) {
                        tx_relay->m_next_inv_send_time = NextInvToInbounds(current_time, INBOUND_INVENTORY_BROADCAST_INTERVAL);
                    } else {
                        tx_relay->m_next_inv_send_time = GetExponentialRand(current_time, OUTBOUND_INVENTORY_BROADCAST_INTERVAL);
                    }
                }
```

This was initially implemented by Pieter Wuille in [#7125](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7125), later improved in [#7840](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7840) and [#13298](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/13298)

---

Related

[Transaction Relay and trickling in Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83018/transaction-relay-and-trickling-in-bitcoin)